# Terminal (macOS) stopped working for Ruby commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

Something very strange happened to me. I installed RoR, finished guide 'getting started with rails', and started to building website. I installed many gems, created a lot of new apps, and then my console stopped responding. I wanted to get to another app through console, typing

> $ cd myapp1

and nothing happened. I just get to another empty line.
To be clear - I used this command multiple times before so many others.

Have you dealt with something like that?

UPDATE : i closed and opened terminal few times then restart whole computer and it was still broken. i just let it go and few minutes later it started to working on oO

STILL. Had anyone this issue?

Comment: Can you post what are you getting?

Comment: What you meant by `i wanted to get to another app through console` ?Have you tried quit terminal app and open again ?

Comment: Try hitting ctrl + d which will interrupt any ongoing prompt.